# Tabulator.js table.getRows() returning array of strings instead of RowComponents

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm doing this in my code:

```
let rows = table.getRows(); //as indicated per https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/update
for (const row in rows) {
  console.log(row);
}
```

There are three rows in my table and my output is:

```
0
1
2
```

Changing `console.log(row);` to `console.log(typeof row);` I found that `getRows()` is returning an array of strings instead of RowComponents. Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: I think you should mention that your question is related to Tabulator in the title and/or body of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use

```
for (const row of rows) { ...
```

instead of

```
for (const row in rows) { ...
```

`for in` will iterate over the **properties** of an object whereas `for of` will iterate the **values**.